# In javaFx is it possible to make rounded corner of a Rectangle except right-bottom?

Tags: java, javafx

Its too easy to make all corner round by using `archWidth()` and `archHeight()`.
But I need only top-left, top-right and left-bottom corner round.
I need to display image where image have top-left, top-right and left-bottom rounded corner. please help me ........

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72949214/javafx-image-with-different-corners  solves the problem of having different corners in an image simultaneously.

Answer (score 4):

If you use a Region, you can set the backgroud radii in CSS:

```
public class FXRadiusTest extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage)
    {
        Region rect = new Region();
        rect.setPrefSize(200, 200);
        rect.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red; -fx-background-radius: 10 10 0 10");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(new Group(rect), 400, 400));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        Application.launch(FXRadiusTest.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks.....its good but how can i add image into it.actually i need an image with top-left, top-right,left-bottom round corner.

Comment: Regions can contain background images with [-fx-background-image](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#region).

Comment: using background image, region lost its shape.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Region instead it allows to define background-radius values for each corner